# python type hint, return same type as input

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

Well I'm considering a case where I have a baseclass with (several) children. I have a function that takes a list of baseclass objects, and returns a new list with these objects in it.

Now if I would use a child class obviously the return is a list of those child class objects: consider the following trivial case:

```
from typing import Sequence, List, TypeVar


class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.CanCalculate = True
        if data is None:
            data = []
            self.CanCalculate = False
        self._mydata = list(data)
        self.multiplier = 1

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._mydata


class ChildClass(BaseClass):
    def sum_mul_data(self):
        return self.multiplier * sum(self.data)


class SecondChildClass(BaseClass):
    def sum_div_data(self):
        return sum(self.data) / self.multiplier


def myFun(input: Sequence[BaseClass]) -> List[BaseClass]:
    out = []
    for n, i in enumerate(input):
        if i.CanCalculate:
            i.multiplier = 10**n
            out.append(i)
    return out


childs = [ChildClass([1,2,3,4]), ChildClass(), ChildClass([1,2,3,4])]

t = myFun(childs)
for idx in t:
    print(idx.sum_mul_data())


childs = [SecondChildClass([1,2,3,4]), SecondChildClass(), SecondChildClass([1,2,3,4])]

t = myFun(childs)
for idx in t:
    print(idx.sum_div_data())
```

Legal code: however pycharm (and the standard type hints) shows an error during static code analysis:
"unresolved attribute reference" @ `idx.sum_mul_data()`

Now apparently this is due to pycharm thinking the return of the function is of type "BaseClass" - not a child. So how would I state: "return same type as input"?

I tried using a typevar: `T = TypeVar("T", BaseClass)`, though that gave an actual error, that a single contraint can't be used in `TypeVar`. Interestingly using `T = TypeVar("T", BaseClass, ChildClass)` did work, and pycharm correctly deduced the type(hint) for sum_div_data.

Comment: You seem to have solved your own problem. Docs seems to say that `T = TypeVar("T")` will give you a totally generic type hint and, as you have seen, your `T = TypeVar("T", BaseClass, ChildClass)`  works.

Comment: @quamrana but that would mean that the location of `myFun` has an understanding of at least one such child class. - On top of that it seems totally arbitrary why the reference to the `ChildClass` is there: why not a reference to `SecondChildClass` or something else?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use typevars with an upper bound: do `T = TypeVar('T', bound=BaseClass)` instead of `T = TypeVar('T', BaseClass)`.

Details:

- When you do something like `T = TypeVar('T', ClassA, ClassB, ClassC...)`, you're  creating a [type variable with a value restriction](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#type-variables-with-value-restriction). That is, you're insisting that `T` must be exactly one of the classes you listed.

  This is why doing `T = TypeVar('T', ClassA)` is disallowed: the typevar can only be equal to one class, so you might as well just use the `ClassA` type directly.
- When you do something like `T = TypeVar('T', bound=ClassA)`, you're creating a [type variable with an upper bound](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#type-variables-with-upper-bounds). You're insisting that `T` must either be `ClassA`, or any of its subclasses.